# Add new voices for Windows Phone (WinRT) speech synthesizer

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, text-to-speech

Using the speech-to-text WinRT API:

```
private async Task SynthesizeSpeech(string text)
{
    var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    var media = new MediaElement();
    var stream = await m_Synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
    m_Media.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
    m_Media.Play();
}
```

You can set the synthesizer's voice by choosing from the available ones on the device:

```
var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
    .FirstOrDefault(voice => voice.Language.StartsWith("es"));
```

My Windows Phone (8.1) includes a voices: an English, Japanese, and Chinese, male and female.

My question is: is there any way to install new voices onto the device (or better yet, include them with my app)?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Speech lets you install new speech voices onto the phone. (I still don't know how to install it from a resource in my app, or at least provide a link to the user of my app to install it.)